# Android: Is it ok to use the google map url instead of calling from google map api ?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, webview

On my device, I am using android 19 with no google play services. I can't use the Google Map View coz i think that is using Google Play Services. When we do browsing I call this link http://map.google.com/maps?q=Address, can I do that on my webview to show the map.

Comment: The question is, do you want to sacrifice quality to support devices which are going to be near obsolete in coming few months?

Comment: Make your minimum SDK to 21 or 22 may be, and implement proper Google Maps SDK

Comment: I understand.. but I can't do that coz the device i am having has been set to be sdk 19 by the manufacturer. I am not dealing with the consumers' phone

Comment: You can use emulator till you purchase a new device. At the end, you are making the app for users but not u

Comment: what about the maps.googleapi.com, what is the different

Comment: Both are one and the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Last question, how the website who are using google map what do they use. If it's no longer work in the future

Comment: Do not mix the mobile with web. Web SDKs are different from Mobile. for web, you update chrome/safari/firefox and for mobile you update Android and iOS. Both are independant.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of understand but still a little confusion. do you mean it's still functional on the web environment on desktop but not on the web mobile version...

Comment: It will function on mobile too. But when you develop for mobile, it should be for mobile. Using webview for native function is too too bad. It will be just like viewing a map on chrome instead of app.